# How to display view on top of keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

In my case you want to display the switch between the custom and the system keyboard "instantly", that is, without animation system and the appearance of my.

Is this potentially possible on UN-rooted devices? Just as far as I know there is no such possibility as it would be a security hole (allowing the system keyboard to hang on top of the "listener" content that would steal your data), but refutation or confirmation is not found.

UPD. I find solution with popup. But this solution strange)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a tricky behavior, I don't think there is a clean way to do that on Android